# How to change pip version on google cloud

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, pip

mistakenly first i installed python 3.6 then install pip,then i install python 3.8 after that i checked the pip version its shows me.

```
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Can i change to

```
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: pip 20.1.1 is the latest stable version; do you want to rollback to an earlier version or something?

Comment: @smoggers no i don't want rollback, i am confusing why pip -V mapping with 3.6 instead of 3.8.

Comment: Both answers below are good. Check your PATH to make sure the correct Python installation is present and remove the other. I would also uninstall Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure `pip` is using the python version you desire, you can use:

```
python3.8 -m pip ...
```

instead of the bare:

```
pip ...
```

Comment: i am confusing why pip -V mapping with 3.6 instead of 3.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install pip
$ python3.6 -m pip uninstall pip
```